# Applications of Sampling from SK Ising Model

Tags: ising-model

I have written a program for Monte Carlo sampling from Sherrington-Kirkpatrick (SK) Ising model. I have two questions about it:

1- What are some applications of it? I already know training Boltzmann machines and solving optimization problems can be an application, but I was wondering if there are other applications as well.

2- Lets say I have generated $1000$ samples from a high dimensional (say $1000$ spin) Ising model. We don't know what the exact distribution is, so I cannot tell if my samples are correct. I was wondering if there is any form of visualization or any criteria that I can evaluate the performance of my sampler. Or is there a way to generate an SK Ising instance with known distribution so I can compare my samples with the exact results?

Thanks